# Sending email with link does not recieved with link

Tags: android, email

Im trying to send an email from my app, i see the link as should in my email client on my android, but when i check the email receiver, there is no links.

Here is my Code:

```
        emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/html");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { "" });
        emailIntent.putExtra(
                android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                MainActivity.getCurrentActivity().getString(
                        R.string.mailTitle));
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                Html.fromHtml(text));
```

'text' is html.

Thank You.

Comment: Html.fromHtml doesn't do what you think it does. It formats a Spannable for display in a TextView. What happens if you just put text as parameter ?

Comment: I was out of office for few days, I'll check it soon.

Comment: If i just put 'text' I get a raw html text, the links are sent and marked but i can see the html tags as well, in the reciever and in the sender clients app (gmail in this case).

Comment: does your html contains all the proper tags (html, body, may be doctype, even ?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
          private void sendMail(String[] emailaddressList)
             {

      Intent sendIntent;
      sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      sendIntent.setType("text/html");
      String body="Go to this link \n\n\n";
      String link=Html.fromHtml(body)+"\"https://www.google.com"";
      sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Mail test");
      sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, link);

      sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,emailaddressList);

      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send Mail"));        
              }
```